# Should I replace the two rear tires or just the flattened one?

Tags: tires, civic, replacements, sedan

One of my rear right tires need to be replaced and the other rear tire and all the other front tires are at 8/32 as in the picture .

For a Sedan driving regularly 12 miles on highway everyday should I replace both tires.?

[image]

Comment: Why is one tire worn much more than the others? That's a question to look at first..

Comment: Same wear and tear but got flattened on my way and was damaged

Comment: Americans and their units... For the rest of the world: 8/32 is 6mm of tire thread vs ~8mm on new ones. What is the age of your current tires?